# How to get the correct InputID while using InsertUI in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I have a question about InsertUI and the respective InputID of the elements.

In the example below, the inputID of selectizeInput "Number_Product1_1"   shows the output for the 1. Division in the boxOutput "InputID".

If this InputID is used as input for the boxOutput "Total", no output is displayed.

If more Divisions are added, the quantity of Product1 (in the example below '50') of the 1. division is the output in the boxOutput "Total" of the following divisions. But why is this output not shown for the 1. division?

I am confused. Can someone explain to me why this shift occurs?

Thanks for your inputs!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Identify Total amount/Divison"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  width = 12,
  # Buttons to add/remove a question
  actionButton("add", "Add Divison"),
  actionButton("remove", "Remove Divison"),
  div(id = "questions",
      style = "border: 1px solid silver;")
),
mainPanel(
)))



# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
values <- reactiveValues(num_questions = 0) 
# Add a division
observeEvent(input$add, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {

values$num_questions <- values$num_questions + 1
num <- values$num_questions
ui = tags$div(
  insertUI(
    selector = "#questions", where = "beforeEnd",
    splitLayout(
      cellWidths = c("20%","20%", "20%", "20%", "20%"), 
      cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 3px"),
      id = paste0("question", num),
      textAreaInput(inputId = paste0("Division_", num),
                    label = paste0(num, ". Division:"),
                    placeholder = "Placeholder"),

      selectizeInput(inputId =paste0("Number_Product1_", num),
                         label = paste0("Product1"), isolate(seq(from = 50, to = 100000, by = 50)), multiple=FALSE),
      selectizeInput(inputId =paste0("Number_Product2_", num),
                     label = paste0("Product2"), isolate(seq(from = 0, to = 100000, by = 50)), multiple=FALSE),
      box(
        title = "Total", width = 12, background = "black",


        input$Number_Product1_1),   #### Input from selectizeInput "Product 1" 



       box(
        title = "inputID", width = 12, background = "black",

        paste0("Number_Product1_", num))  #### inputID's of the selectizeinput "Product 1"
      )))

})

# Remove a division
observeEvent(input$remove, {
num <- values$num_questions
# Don't let the user remove the very first Row
if (num == 1) {
  return()
}
removeUI(selector = paste0("#question", num))
values$num_questions <- values$num_questions - 1
})

}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have to come up with a better explanation, Meanwhile that error is fixed.

My understanding is that within `insertUI` you are trying to access an id whose value would be created only after `insertUI` hence I tried to render it separately and assigned the output of it to the `box` value.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Identify Total amount/Divison"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 12,
      # Buttons to add/remove a question
      actionButton("add", "Add Divison"),
      actionButton("remove", "Remove Divison"),
      div(id = "questions",
          style = "border: 1px solid silver;")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )))



# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(num_questions = 0) 
  # Add a division
  observeEvent(input$add, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE,{

    values$num_questions <- values$num_questions + 1
    num <- values$num_questions
    #ui = tags$div(
   # observe({


      insertUI( immediate = TRUE,
        selector = "#questions", where = "beforeEnd",

        splitLayout(
          cellWidths = c("20%","20%", "20%", "20%", "20%"), 
          cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 3px"),
          id = paste0("question", num),
          textAreaInput(inputId = paste0("Division_", num),
                        label = paste0(num, ". Division:"),
                        placeholder = "Placeholder"),

          selectizeInput(inputId =paste0("Number_Product1_", num),
                         label = paste0("Product1"), isolate(seq(from = 50, to = 100000, by = 50)), multiple=FALSE,
                         selected = 50),
          selectizeInput(inputId =paste0("Number_Product2_", num),
                         label = paste0("Product2"), isolate(seq(from = 0, to = 100000, by = 50)), multiple=FALSE),



          box(
            title = "Total", width = 12, background = "black",

            print( input$Number_Product1_1),

            textOutput("total")

          ),   #### Input from selectizeInput "Product 1" 



          box(
            title = "inputID", width = 12, background = "black",

            paste0("Number_Product1_", num))  #### inputID's of the selectizeinput "Product 1"
        ))
      #)
   # })
  })

  #observe({

   # require(input$Number_Product1_1)
    output$total <- renderText({
      input[["Number_Product1_1"]] 
    })
 # })

  # Remove a division
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    num <- values$num_questions
    # Don't let the user remove the very first Row
    if (num == 1) {
      return()
    }
    removeUI(selector = paste0("#question", num))
    values$num_questions <- values$num_questions - 1
  })

}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @amrrs ! Clever solution, I would not have thought of such a thing. +1!

Comment: Do you mean that if the drop down changes, this should also change?